# Digest: DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Error Next JS 13

[image: 1]

For some reason when I fetch data in page.tsx I am getting this error : Digest: DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE

Fetching data in pages.tsx
Using Nextjs 13.1
Data is from supabase 2

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran into this error using the `useSession` hook.  When I ran it with `suspense: false`, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

I just added `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` to my `page.tsx` file and it worked for me

Found the solution in the documentation https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/segment-config

Comment: Same solution necessary in NextJS 14.

Answer (score 3):

### I was facing this issue with cookies() Function Issue

It's worth noting that the issue also occurs when trying to use the cookies() function from 'next/headers' in a statically generated page. The cookies() function allows you to access cookies, but when used in the context of static generation, it triggers the same error: "DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: headers at staticGenerationBailout"

my code:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

// with following inside the function

const supabase    = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });
```

[reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config)

So in order to solve this:

I used:

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Just add this line on top of your layout page and you should be ok

Comment: That works, but why tho?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are fetching different data for different users and Next needs you to point this out specifically, which doesn't happen in dev mode.

And to avoid the bad experience of white screen, it is recommended to add error.tsx page and use try catch to handle fetch and server api

Comment: I got this in a normal get API call. How is this even related?

Comment: @ShouryaShikhar why don't you modify your question and let us know what exactly your code is, error message is not enough